# Compiled label points towards the wrong label

Tags: cross-referencing, labels, autoref

I am struggling with an issue where I defined several labels that are wrongly compiled by latex.

I have several chapters with numerous paragraphs, sections, tables, and equations, for instance, that are associated with labels.

For instance:

```
\paragraph{My paragraph A}
\label{par:my_paragraph_a}

Lorem ipsum
\begin{equation}
    \label{eq:my_equation_a}
    a = 5
\end{equation}
```

In most cases, everything is fine, and the displayed label matches the referred item, with the link pointing toward the right object, but I have 2/3 cases where the label is wrong and the links point toward the wrong object.

For instance, using `\autoref{par:my_paragraph_a}` with the code above could be compiled as Equation X.
I tried to recompile from scratch (on Overleaf), and I tried to move the labels in the `\paragraph{}` argument, but nothing changed.

The logs do not seem to yield any error or warning.

Would anyone have an idea of what is actually going on and how to solve this :-)?

Comment: As always on this site, please provide a full minimal example that displays your problem. Then others can test that exact code on their system and provide advice.

Comment: Note that `\paragraph` normally does not give a number so `\label{par:my_paragraph_a}` would not refer to something that `\autoref` can use.

Comment: or more specifically `\label{par:my_paragraph_a}` will refer to the last referenceable item. which is probably the current `\subsubsection`

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please extend your code to a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Thank you for all your feedback!

I did not manage to reproduce this issue on a shorter example, so that's why I didn´t copy-paste the 180 pages here but thank you very much for the advice :-)
Thanks to your replies, I realize that, indeed, in this format I don't have a number, and it's probably also the only time I reference a paragraph on the entire chapter so I hope this was the issue :D

That being said, do you know how to reference a paragraph then without using numbers?

Comment: Well what do you expect the ref command to do if there is no number? Should it write "reference to an unnumbered paragraph"?

Comment: you should not copy paste a 180 page example but you could easily edit your example so it demonstrates the problem, just add `\documentclass{article}\begin{document}\section{xxx}...\end{document}`